# Are we able to customize icon rendering procedure in Windows file explorer?

Tags: windows, icons, explorer

Is Windows providing APIs or hooks to file icon rendering procedure of `explorer.exe` that allow us to use any random image as file icon in a programmatical way? Moreover, could we do that for folder icon?

For example, are we able to inject the logic below (use Javascript as example) into that procedure?

```js
// use a function to listen on any file icon rendering event
function onFileIconRendering(fullFilename) // fullFilename, string, e.g., "D://folder1/folder2/file3.exe"
{
  if (fullFilename.includes('1')) return './1.png' // use our own image to replace default icons
  else if (fullFilename.includes('2')) return './2.png'
  // ... more any random logic
}
```